# Android - There is a space at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am building an Android application in which I would like to show the bottom navigation view inside the Drawer layout. And I am seeing the unnecessary space at the bottom.

[image]

Here is XML file.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/content_main"
                layout="@layout/content_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <include
                    app:viewModel="@{viewModel}"
                    android:id="@+id/side_navigation"
                    layout="@layout/side_nav_header" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_27sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_item_bg"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_6sdp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorScreenBackground"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_no_internet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorfcf2e6"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_2sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_signal_off"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_signal_off"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_signal_off_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:text="@{LocaleHelper.onAttach(context).getString(R.string.text_info_no_internet_title)}"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_6ssp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_signal_off_desc"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_signal_off"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="@string/text_info_no_internet_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_signal_off_desc"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:text="@{LocaleHelper.onAttach(context).getString(R.string.text_info_no_internet_desc)}"
                    android:textColor="@color/color2e3f47"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_4ssp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_signal_off"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_signal_off_title"
                    tools:text="@string/text_info_no_internet_desc" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you point where is the space that is unnecessary?

Comment: you can notice at the bottom of this screenshot. There is a semi transparent layout occupied a space at the bottom.